# Add custom 'li' element to existing ul list in filepond

Tags: filepond

Hi I am trying add custom 'li' to the list of files.

```
let element = document.createElement("li");
    element.innerHTML = "hello";
    let ulEle = document.querySelector(".filepond--list");
    let liItem = document.querySelector(".filepond--item");
    ulEle.insertBefore(element, liItem);
```

I can see element inserted but filepond's ul li item is overflowing my custom element.
When I try to modify css, than it doesn't work as intended.

please assist

Answer (score 0):

The styling/positioning of the file items in the list is very custom to allow for all the animations (it's done from JavaScript), adding your own elements to the list will not work.

You can however add elements to a list item. To do this I advise to write a custom plugin, the best starting point I think is the [image-edit plugin](https://github.com/pqina/filepond-plugin-image-edit).